# The way to combine two BERT model trained from scratch on different corpus to be one model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, pytorch, tpu

I want to train BERT from scratch on a different language, with almost 150GB data (corpus), and I need to end this in maximum one month.
In some articles, I read that the time it took to train the language models like BERT on like data I have was more than a month over 8 TPUs.

I have two different accounts (we assume it is account-1 and account-2) on Google Cloud TPUs service, which offered me free TPUs for a month. I need to benefit from those different accounts and ending the training process during the free month.

So, I plan to do:

1- Divide the corpus into roughly equal parts, becomes corpus-1, corpus-2.

2- Training two model from scratch (BERT-1, BERT-2), each of them with a section of the corpus(corpus-1, corpus-2), and each model will train on a different account.

3- Saving each model after training.

The question is:

1- Is there any way to combine these two model to be one model?
(i.e, BERT-1 + BERT-2 = BERT-3, where BERT-3 becomes as if it has been trained on all the corpus=150GB), Is this possible?

Lastly, the combined model (BERT-3), I will fine-tune it on different NLP tasks.

I appreciate any contribution. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `Is there any way to combine these two model to be one model?`, are you talking about ensemble? or some form of concatenation?

Comment: I don't know precisely if one of these methods will lead to what is required (BERT-3= BERT-1+BERT-2), where BERT-3 I will fine-tune it on NLP task. I think the closest way may be the ensemble. Can you tell me if it will give me the needed model? and how?

Comment: Ensemble would work for you. For more information can refer https://towardsdatascience.com/ensembling-huggingfacetransformer-models-f21c260dbb09